# iPhone slider save user preference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, settings, preferences

I need to save a slider preference in my Settings.bundle.

I'm using the following code to write to the Settings.bundle:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:mySlider.value forKey:@"TimerSliderKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And the  following code to read from the Settings.bundle:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int valueForSlider = [defaults2 integerForKey:@"TimerSliderKey"];
NSLog(@"The saved slider value is %@" , valueForSlider);
```

This code does not work. Can someone give me some replacement code that I could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
NSLog(@"The saved slider value is %@" , valueForSlider);
```

You need to use the `%d` format specifier, `%@` is the format specifier to send the `description` message to the argument.

```
NSLog(@"The saved slider value is %d" , valueForSlider);
```

Here's a list of format specifiers:

[image]

See the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The other, and perhaps the real, problem is that UISlider's value ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 by default. Storing it as an integer, you will only ever see 0 or 1 due to truncation.

You should store it as a floating point instead to fully preserve the value of the slider.

Comment: Thank you for your input(+1), I had previously set the time from 0.0 to 10.0.

Comment: Then you will only get values of 0,1,2,3...10, the floating point component of the value will still be lost. If this is intentional, then that is not a problem. Otherwise you should store the value as a float to avoid losing part of the user's preference.

Answer (score 0):

**use this one...**

```
[**yourslider** addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:)
                           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"value"]) {

    yourslider.value= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]floatForKey:@"value"];

  }


**--save your value in this method**

-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{

    NSLog(@"slider value = %f", sender.value);


   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setFloat:sender.value forKey:@"value"];

}
```